# move_uploaded_file and the copy

Tags: php, upload, copy

I am trying to upload a tmp file and then copy it. But it is not appearing in the second folder, is there an overlay or something I have to watch?

```
$uploadPath = '/.../..../image/';
$uploadPathpreview = '/.../..../blog/';

if ($counter == 0){
$preview_file = $uploadPath . DS . 'preview_' . date("Ymd-Hi-") . $img_name;
$preview_file_save = $uploadPathpreview . DS . 'preview_' . date("Ymd-Hi-") . $img_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $preview_file)){
    $tmp = $preview_file;
    $new = $preview_file_save;
                                }
copy($tmp,$new);
```

The file in image exists by the way. And I tried it without the if()

Comment: if the `m_u_f` fails, you never generate `$tmp` and `$new`, and `copy()` fails outright. `copy()` should be inside the `if()` block, so it only runs if the move was successful.

Comment: Are all those dots actually in the 2 path statements at the top of the script

Comment: Where does `$tmp_name` get set to something

Comment: You need to put the `copy` inside the if statement, because if the `move_uploaded_file` fail won't try to copy an inexistent file.

Anyway, the `$tmp_name` variable appear to be unset, check the `$tmp_name` and `$preview_file` variables to be set and valid paths.

Comment: $tmp_name is set above sorry and the dots are to hide the structure of the var/www ... 

It is not necessary to put it in the if, because I can see the file gets put where I want it, after I execute it.